# how to query api or database with axios where object value is not the same

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, axios

Is there a way to query an api or database with axios where an object element value is not the same as another object element value

Example: I am trying to get all titles ("title") where the "_ref" is not the same

```
{
    "__v": 0,
    "_ref": "6149290b197615d32c515dab",
    "title": "First Title",
    "details": "first"

  },
  {
    "__v": 0,
    "_ref": "6149290b197615d32c515dab",
    "title": "First Title",
    "details": "second"

  },
  {
    "__v": 0,
    "_ref": "2805jkdfg763",
    "title": "Third Title",
    "details": "third"

  }
```

```
  return await axios
    .get('http://localhost/api', {
      params: {
        _ref: != _ref
      },
    })
    .then(response => {
      EventRegister.emit('MongoDb_Data', response.data);
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

desired results would be:

```
First Title
Third Title
```

Comment: That entirely depends on the specific API, not on axios (which is just making the HTTP request.)

Comment: I think question is not related to axios but related to how to process data where one attribute is common in different object list. I have suggest answer. Please check if you are looking for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = [
  {
    "__v": 0,
    "_ref": "6149290b197615d32c515dab",
    "title": "First Title",
    "details": "first"
  },
  {
    "__v": 0,
    "_ref": "6149290b197615d32c515dab",
    "title": "First Title",
    "details": "second"
  },
  {
    "__v": 0,
    "_ref": "2805jkdfg763",
    "title": "Third Title",
    "details": "third"
  }
]

const refmap = data.reduce((acc, { _ref, title }) => {
  acc[_ref] = {
    title,
  };
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log('c', Object.values(refmap));
```

you will get the array of desired output.

```
console.log('c', Object.values(refmap).map( a => a.title));  // final output
```

Comment: So are you suggesting that I would have to pull down all of the data then filter and adjust the data on the client side

Comment: oh I thought you are getting all data in call from DB , if it's not the case then above is not a good practise .   Above solution for the if you have all data in hand.

not sure , how it can handle on DB side.